# Using item value as part of the select code

Tags: sql, oracle, report, oracle-apex

I'm trying to use a feature on oracle apex 20 that was working fine in apex 5.1.
I have a interactive report, and at the very and I add value of the item like this:
'''

```
SELECT                                                        /* PARALLEL(4)*/
       o.id,
       NULL
           pregled,
       o.OS_TIP,
       o.SIFRA,
       o.OS_TIP_PRETH,
       o.PRETHODI,
       o.OS_TIP_MASTER,
       o.MASTER,
       u.naziv || ' - ' || o.UGOVARATELJ
           Ugovaratelj,
       p.naziv || ' - ' || o.POSREDNIK
           Posrednik,
       t.naziv || ' ' || o.TRAJANJE
           Trajanje,
       o.POCETAK_OSIGURANJA,
       o.ISTEK_OSIGURANJA,
       o.POCETAK_PREMIJE,
       o.KRAJ_PREMIJE,
       o.DATUM_IZDANJA,
       o.BROJ_RATA,
       o.PREMIJA,
       (  SELECT CASE
                     WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN (
                              TO_DATE (osd.kraj_premije, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
                              TO_DATE (osd.pocetak_premije, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) <
                          12
                     THEN
                         ROUND (SUM (st.premija_neto), 2)
                     ELSE
                         ROUND (
                               SUM (st.premija_neto)
                             / NVL (
                                   (  (FLOOR (
                                           MONTHS_BETWEEN (
                                               TO_DATE (osd.kraj_premije,
                                                        'DD.MM.YYYY'),
                                               TO_DATE (osd.pocetak_premije,
                                                        'DD.MM.YYYY'))))
                                    / 12),
                                   1),
                             2)
                 END    godisnja
            FROM os_dokument osd, stavka_dokumenta st
           WHERE     st.os_tip(+) = osd.os_tip
                 AND st.sifra(+) = osd.sifra
                 AND osd.os_tip(+) = o.os_tip
                 AND osd.sifra(+) = o.sifra
        GROUP BY osd.pocetak_premije, osd.kraj_premije)
           godisnja_premija,
       r.naziv || ' - ' || o.REFERENT
           Referent,
       prodaja.F_STATUS_POLICE (O.OS_TIP, O.SIFRA)
           STATUS_POLISE,
       (SELECT forma
          FROM odobrenje
         WHERE odobrenje = o.odobrenje)
           status_odobravanja,
       sd.grupacija || sd.grupa || '.' || sd.cjenik
           tarifa,
       dms.postoji_dokument (o.id)
           postoji_dokumentacija,
       (SELECT k.tekst
          FROM os_dokument_komentar k
         WHERE k.OS_DOKUMENT_ID = o.id AND k.indikator = 1)
           poruka,
       o.korisnik,
       DECODE ((SELECT k.tekst
                  FROM os_dokument_komentar k
                 WHERE k.OS_DOKUMENT_ID = o.id AND k.indikator = 1),
               NULL, 'background-color:white',
               'background-color:lightblue')
           CSS_STYLE_PORUKA,
       DECODE (dms.postoji_dokument (o.id),
               'NE', 'background-color:white"',
               'background-color:lightblue')
           CSS_STYLE_DMS
  FROM OS_DOKUMENT       o,
       in2_stranka       p,
       in2_stranka       r,
       in2_stranka       u,
       in2_stranka       pl,
       trajanje          t,
       stavka_dokumenta  sd
 WHERE     o.posrednik = p.jmbg(+)
       AND o.referent = r.jmbg(+)
       AND o.ugovaratelj = u.jmbg(+)
       AND o.trajanje = t.trajanje(+)
       AND (o.os_tip = 'P08' OR o.os_tip LIKE 'N1%')
       AND o.id = sd.id_os_dokument(+)
       AND sd.rb(+) = 1
       AND o.platitelj = pl.jmbg(+)
       &FILTER.
```

'''
FILTER is a hidden page item that is set with a process on page load, and it contains some code. In the simplest version, it will contain "and 1=1", or it can contain some additional condition like "and o.POSREDNIK = '12345'"
As I said in Apex 5.1 this works just fine. But in Apex 20 I can not even validate the code in code editor, I get
"
ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

ORA-06550: line 53, column 27: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

"
Same select without &FILTER. at the end works just fine.
Any suggestion how to get this to work in Apex 20? Or how to insert some code into the select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, it doesn't work any more.

However, it will work if you choose **function body returning SQL query** as the source type (instead of SQL query).

Really nice feature of Apex 20 is that it automatically converts your query into the `RETURN` clause, using the q-quoting mechanism to prevent possible *single quote* issues. So: you just have to change the source type - Apex will do the rest for you and the report should work properly. At least, it does for me.